# Stuck with NopCommerce First Changes Not Showing up

Tags: razor, nopcommerce

Hello everyone and thank you for your time.

I am a developper, I have 1 year experience with C# and 3 with Java, but not with NopCommerce.
I downloaded NopCommerce 4.20 and imported it into my Visual Studio 2019.
Arranged some problems and finally run it and applied a Theme I bought.

But, when trying to start modifying the code, it does not take any effect.

I thought this could have relation with compilation problems (I already saw the Topic for the error on  compile 'ClearPluginAssemblies' and 'SaveLocalesFolders'). So the only way to get rid of it was to disable the MSBuild of this little project (which is used to clean duplicated Plugin directories by NopCommerce itself).

I have a bunch of questions:
1. What do I need to do with ClearPluginAssemblies? Configure it so that it doesn't give me more problems anymore when running the WebApp? Or disabling it and deleting manually the Plugin folder, after every compile, but before Starting the Webapp 'Node.Web'?

2. Exactly, which folder should I delete on this case? (For me it's ok to do it manually, I am starting to touch NopCommerce in order to see wether my uncle Business could work or not).
3. If 'ClearPluginAssemblies' do not affect to the compilation process... What can I do to start modifying the code ? Changes don't take effect on the Local instance of the Online Shop I am running! (for example, I want to add an element in the product page)

Visual Studio does not Highlight the *.cshtml files, it opens them only with white text, so I think it isn't recognising properly? Do I really compile my changes? They don't show up...

I am doing refresh, clean, compile, all the stuff for webapps, but I can't even start programming...
For 4 hours, I followed the next Topics but I couldn't get to solve it:

https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/issues/4116
https://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/topic/71353/420-fails-to-build-clearpluginassembliesproj
https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/issues/2728

What I need in the End is Start Modifying the Code and Generating the different Views.
I think I can delete manually Repeated NopCommerce default plugins (but not My theme Plugins), or with a Batch, whatever.

Thank you very much in advance !!

Comment: Are you trying to develop/modify a plugin or changing the source code of nopCommerce projects?

Comment: I don't know. I was trying to change the visualization of a product page, so I thing the nopCommerce Project. Anyway, I decided not to continue with that. thank you